# View child/ View children from parent component to child component

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I want to ViewChild from parent component to child component.

```
class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChild('CommentSection') commentBox: ElementRef
}

class ChildComponent {}
```

child.component.html

```
<textarea #CommentSection>
 </textarea>
```

Is it possible?

I am getting 'undefined' in afterviewInit function

Comment: Please make a [mcve] on stackblitz.

Answer (score 3):

You can access Child Component like this

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, AfterViewInit, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { MyComponent } from './mycomponent.component';

export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit
{

    @ViewChildren(MyComponent) childrenComponent: QueryList<MyComponent>;

    public ngAfterViewInit(): void
    {
        this.childrenComponent.changes.subscribe((comps: QueryList<MyComponent>) =>
        {
            // Now you can access the child component
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ketan
Can I access the element in child component through it and hide/show it?